# Python Key Error for Instagram Auth Token

Tags: python, pycurl, instagram-api

I found some code online for Instagram Auto Like script.
My current issue is this error
http://s1.postimg.org/griyd3pjz/code_sample.png
the error you see is for the first blacked out key
The relevant code is:

```
# Function to encode the string with the IP and ID of the picture then like it
def encodeAndRequest(id):

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    signature = hmac.new(str(profile['********************************']['********************************']), profile['IP'], sha256).hexdigest()
    header = '|'.join([profile['IP'], signature])
    header = ["X-Insta-Forwarded-For: " + header]

    url = INSTAGRAM_API + id + "/likes"
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, "access_token=" + str(profile['CREDENTIALS']['ACCESS_TOKEN']))
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, header)
    c.perform()

    response = str(c.getinfo(c.HTTP_CODE))
    c.close()

    return response
```

Any ideas on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: where is `profile` being assigned? I'm pretty sure that's the problem.

Comment: You are getting a key error on profile and I don't see where profile is instantiated.

Comment: Even though it uses hmac.new ?

Comment: Would it be as easy as adding profile = [key] [key] above c = pycurl.Curl() ?